# How was 言 created by adding one mark to 舌?

Tags: glyph-origin

To create [言 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A8%80#Chinese), mustn't you add more than one mark to 舌? Sorry for not being able to visualize abstractly!

> Ideogram (*[指事](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%8C%87%E4%BA%8B#Chinese)*): 言 was created by adding a mark to [舌](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%88%8C#Chinese) to indicate movement of the tongue.[[1]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A8%80#cite_note-1) This indicates speech where 舌 is a mouth ([口](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8F%A3#Chinese)) with a tongue sticking out.

Answer (score 7):

The description

> 言 was created by adding a mark to 舌

should really be

> 言 was created by adding **one or two horizontal marks to the top of** 舌

Details aside, it is a fairly accurate *character component arrangement* description. For it to make sense, you have to first determine the shape of the *character components* that it's talking about.

Wiktionary's [glyph evolution table of 「舌」](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%88%8C#Glyph_origin) doesn't show enough examples of 「舌」 in [oracle bone script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) for the description to immediately make sense. The shape we have today is originally inherited from Series 1, shown below:

**Series 1**

[image: Series 1 shape of 「舌」, with more tongue forks drawn]

> <sub>Crossed out samples are ones where *spittle* is also drawn, which doesn't survive today.</sub>

The confusion arises because Wiktionary is only showing a sample of 「舌」 from Series 2 below:

**Series 2**

[image: Series 2 「舌」 shapes, with less tongue forks drawn]

It doesn't really matter which shape of 「舌」 that 「言」 is derived from, 「言」 is still made up from one or two horizontal marks added to the top of 「舌」:

- 「言」 derived from Series 1 「舌」:

  <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
  [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
  [image: 「言」 as one horizontal mark above Series 1 「舌」]
  [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)499
  [合集30697](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=30697&jgwfl=)</kbd>
- 「言」 derived from Series 2 「舌」:

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image: 「言」 as one horizontal mark above Series 2 shape of 「舌」]
  [拾](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)8.1
  [合集21082](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=21082&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>商
  甲
  [image: 「言」 as two horizontal marks above Series 2 shape of 「舌」]
  [乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)766
  [合集22072](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=22072&jgwfl=)</kbd>

You can even get 「言」 derived from 「舌」 with spittle drawn:

<kbd>商
甲
[image: 「言」 as one horizontal mark above 「舌」 from series 2 shape with spittle]
[後](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.41.9
[合集21631](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=21631&jgwfl=)</kbd>

---

#### Glyph origins summary

<kbd>商
甲
[image: 「舌」]
[甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)499
[合集30697](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=30697&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image: 「舌」]
中山王方壺
[集成9735](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9735&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image: 「舌」]
秦律十八1
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>[西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image: 「舌」]
[老子](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao_Te_Ching)・甲
[馬王堆帛書](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawangdui_Silk_Texts)</kbd>
<kbd>[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image: 「舌」]</kbd>

「言」 (*to speak*) was originally comprised from one or two horizontal marks 「一・二」 added to the top of 「舌」 (*tongue*). The shape which survives today is made up from two horizontal marks 「二」 on top of a 「舌」 shape coming from Series 1.

「舌」 is no longer evident in 「言」 due to some minor shape corruptions to the *forked tongue* shape occurring post-[Qin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty). Compare [「音」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1497), which is actually comprised from 「言」 with a differentiating mark added inside of the 「口」 part of 「言」.

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Answer (score 1):

In 甲骨文 form, you can see it clearly.

Please see 舌 and 言 in the right side of picture in [this website](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/oraclePiece.php?piece=%E8%88%8C).